# Filter ads in Admob or another ad network to display movie trailers

Tags: ios, video, admob, movie

Is it possible to filter ads in Admob to display movie trailers? As far as I understand I can add filter to display only video ads, disabling image and text, but is it possible to filter the type of video? If not - is there some ad network that allows it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good amount of control to block/allow categories by going to your account on admob and selecting the ad and changing the settings.  Very simple to do from there.